# Why am I receiving error 0x80070643 trying to run aspnet_regiis for v2.0

Tags: .net-2.0

I am trying to install .net v2.0 using "aspnet_regiis -i" ... and I keep getting this error: "Operation failed 0x80070643, fatal error doing installation".

any ideas of what i can do?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976982

Comment: Thank you it does seem like this is the way to correct this. I will let you know if it works.